# Login Redirect to wrong location

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

When I login instead of being redirected to `dashboard` I get redirected to `/` in my auth controller I have commented out the following line however I still get redirected to the wrong location why?

I have cleared the cache `php artisan cache:clear` with no luck

**Line Commented Out:**

`protected $redirectTo = '/';`

**Login Function:**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{   
   $credentials = $this->getLoginCredentials($request);

   if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
   {
    redirect()->intended('dashboard');
   }
   return redirect()->back();

}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {

    /* Admin Auth */
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
    Route::get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.admin'], function(){
    /*Admin Dashboard Routes */
        Route::get('dashboard', 'AdminController@getDashboard');    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `return` for `redirect()`:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{   
   $credentials = $this->getLoginCredentials($request);

   if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
   {
     return redirect()->intended('dashboard');   // here
   }
  return redirect()->back();

}
```